# UnfoldingMap busy looping on draw()

Tags: java, eclipse, processing, unfoldingmap

After some initial trouble, I have now gotten `UnfoldingMap` to work from Eclipse, as described in [the tutorial](http://unfoldingmaps.org/tutorials/getting-started-in-eclipse). This seems to work well, but the `draw()` method gets repeatedly called at high frequency, causing the CPU to go to 100%. This continues indefinitely, even after the whole map has been drawn. Here is the code for the very simple test app:

```
public class SimpleMapApp extends PApplet {

    UnfoldingMap map;

    public void setup() {
        size(800, 600);
        map = new UnfoldingMap(this, new Microsoft.AerialProvider());
    }

    public void draw() {
        map.draw();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main("SimpleMapApp");
    }
}
```

By putting a `sleep()` in the draw method, I can see that it has to do with the tile drawing, a couple of tiles are drawn in every call to `draw()`. I think it also keeps loading map tiles from the server at a high rate; at least Google Maps seems to have banned my IP address, after I used their server in the beginning.

How do I stop the repeated calls to `draw()` after everything has been drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options to control how open the draw method gets called:

1. use [frameRate()](https://processing.org/reference/frameRate_.html)
2. manually pause execution using [noLoop()](https://processing.org/reference/noLoop_.html) and resume it using [loop()](https://processing.org/reference/loop_.html)

Comment: Are you implying that it is by design that the draw() function is called repeatedly? When do I call noLoop() - that is, how do I know that everything has been drawn?

Comment: Yes: draw() is Processing's "infinite loop" being called about 60 times a second. I recommend trying ```frameRate(1)``` first. I haven't used unfolding maps so not sure what the behaviour is (does it load tiles in a background thread or does it rely on Processing's animation thread)

Comment: Ah, thanks, I am unfamiliar with Processing, so didn't know about that. I assume it is for animations, but it is still a peculiar approach.

Comment: No worries. Processing is geared more towards arists and designers getting into programming as a different tool to their practice therefore it tries to be as simple/easy to get started with. (e.g. init stuff in setup(), update/render in draw() and that's it!). You might feel more at home using [Processing javadocs](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#registerMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) to integrate PApplet into your eclipse project as it best suits you